# Replacing a dependency DLL in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have a Visual Studio 2008 project which uses `libcurl.dll` (dynamic linking on run-time). I want to update `libcurl.dll` to a newer version. I manually replaced the dll in the file system, cleaned and built the solution. But during debug, the project is not able to find `libcurl.dll`

Edit: The new dll was built with additional dependencies from libssh2. What all changes should I make in order to use the new DLL?

What is the correct way to upgrade a DLL in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) to find any DLL related issue.
- Check if 32-bit/64-bit system path is causing problem.
- Check if dependent DLL is causing any problem, or if `DllMain` of your DLL is returning failure.

Comment: Thanks. The dependent DLL was built with additional dependencies from libssh2. I will update the question to include this. What all is required to be done to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

DLLs are loaded the same way as executables. They should be either in the same directory or they should be accessible with %PATH%.

Follow these guidelines and VS will find it. Most likely you messed something else.

When you are replacing DLL there is no need to rebuild.

When you buid, the header and the .lib files are used. If you new DLL has the same entries, then you can simply replace the just te DLL file and restart the app.

If your new DLL has different entries or different types of params, then you need new headers, new .lib and then you need to rebuild.

Comment: Thanks. I will modify the question. The new DLL was built using different kind of params. The new dll has been built with dependencies from libssh2. What all do I need to do to make it work?

Comment: It is hard to say exactly what is going on from the available info. Use advises from the other answer. You can try also: place your exe and all required DLLs into one directory and try to run. This may help isolate DLL search aspects from other issues like DllMain return code.

Comment: You are right. I tried using Dependency Walker and it turned out that there were dependent DLLs that I must place. Thanks!